# Is there any way to find out if secure boot is enabled from uefi shell?

Tags: shell, security, uefi

So, my question is in title. I know I can parse nvram variables, but didn't find, where enable flag is stored.
If there is any another way, I'll glad to know, how to resolve my problem.

Comment: Are you asking how to write a program to do this or how to do it using existing UEFI commands? If the latter, it is off topic here.

Comment: @prl, If there is way to do it using existing UEFI commands, that's great, I'd like to go this way, but it seems like there is no way, so I'm trying to find out how can I get this information.
Why is this off topic? There are many questions about Linux bash command lines on stackoverflow. Is this off topic too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UEFI SecureBoot has an indicator variable called "SecureBoot" of  EfiGlobalVariable GUID. It has a value of 0x01 (UINT8) iff SecureBoot is enabled.

You should also check "SetupMode" variable of the same GUID to have a value of 0x00 (UINT8), this indicates that PK, KEK and db are indeed ready and can't be replaced without authentication.